# Cannot build Hibernate SessionFactory when calling from a Servlet

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, servlets

I have a vanilla Tomcat with simple Java Servlets set up where I try to persist person's info to my MySQL database with Hibernate. The application deploys properly, I am able to hit my servlet with proper servlet-mapping but cannot build a SessionFactory to access the database.

Stacktrace:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    meetme.dao.Dao.<clinit>(Dao.java:23)
    meetme.web.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:25)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [meetme.meeting.Person]
    org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:232)
    org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.<init>(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:103)
    org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.<init>(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:147)
    org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:141)
    org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    meetme.dao.Dao.<clinit>(Dao.java:19)
    meetme.web.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:25)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javaws/exceptions/InvalidArgumentException
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:226)
    org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.<init>(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:103)
    org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.<init>(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:147)
    org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:141)
    org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    meetme.dao.Dao.<clinit>(Dao.java:19)
    meetme.web.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:25)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.javaws.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1722)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1573)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:226)
    org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.<init>(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:103)
    org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.<init>(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:147)
    org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:141)
    org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    meetme.dao.Dao.<clinit>(Dao.java:19)
    meetme.web.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:25)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Here's my servlet snippet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String organizerEmail = request.getParameter("email");

        PersonDao dao = new PersonDao();
```

I do a static init of the session factory in `PersonDao` parent abstract class:

```
protected static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

static {
    try {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(); //<-- EXCEPTION!
    } catch (HibernateException ex) {
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed. " + ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
```

It's odd that I'm getting an `ClassNotFoundException` for a  `com.sun.javaws.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException` but only when I hit the Hibernate code. I definitely see it read the Hibernate config file properly so it's not a path issue. It doesn't seem to be able to map my Person class that I use for persisting data. So I threw together a quick standalone test to make sure that my Hibernate stuff is solid:

```
public class MainDaoTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PersonDao dao = new PersonDao();
        System.out.println(dao.getOrganizerByEmail("asdf@asdf.com").getOrganizerGuid());
    }
}
```

Works great. Connects to DB and pulls my organizer Person. Here's the mapped class, just as FYI:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "Participants" )
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "participantId")
    private long participantId;
    @Column(name = "email", unique=true)
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "guid")
    private String organizerGuid;

    public Person(String name, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }

    protected Person() {
        this.name = null;
        this.email = null;
    }

    public Person(String name, String email, String id) {
        this(name, email);
        this.organizerGuid = id;
    }

    // getters and setters...

}
```

Hibernate config:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

        <!-- Database connection details -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://my.url.com</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pass</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <mapping class="meetme.meeting.Person" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

EDIT: Here's the library list for my module in IntelliJ in case versions are clashing:

[image: module's classpath]

Let me know if there's anything else I can post about my setup that may shed more light on the issue. This is similar to this question ([Java - Hibernate Exception - Feedback cannot be mapped [ from Feedback ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233140/java-hibernate-exception-feedback-cannot-be-mapped-from-feedback)) but I already have the class mapping in my config.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javaws/exceptions/InvalidArgumentException, seems you have missing dependency (or) wrong version of jar in classpath.

Comment: Any idea which versions may be clashing? I added my library screenshot.

Comment: Logs also have org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [meetme.meeting.Person], so please check classpath. When Hibernate will intitialize it will try to find the mapped object which it is unable to find.

Comment: All classes get compiled to the WEB-INF/classes directory. Since it's able to call my servlet classes, I assume the classpath is working fine. Is there anything special that I need to specify for Hibernate when deploying to tomcat?